# Получить доступ к объекту PART_... CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Существует настраиваемый контрол, есть частичные элементы помеченные именами PART_[...].
В классе указаны **TemplatePart** атрибуты

> C#

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PartMediaElement, Type = typeof(MediaElement))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartLeftControl, Type = typeof(ContentPresenter))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartTopControl, Type = typeof(ContentPresenter))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartRightControl, Type = typeof(ContentPresenter))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PartBottomControl, Type = typeof(ContentPresenter))]
public class PlayerControl : Control
{
    private const string PartMediaElement = "PART_MediaElement";
    private const string PartTopControl = "PART_TopControl";
    private const string PartLeftControl = "PART_LeftControl";
    private const string PartRightControl = "PART_RightControl";
    private const string PartBottomControl = "PART_BottomControl";
```

> XAML

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:LibraryTheme.Controls">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:PlayerControl}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000000" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:PlayerControl}">
                <Grid x:Name="PART_ContentControlGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <MediaElement UnloadedBehavior="{TemplateBinding UnloadedBehavior}" LoadedBehavior="{TemplateBinding LoadedBehavior}" x:Name="PART_MediaElement" Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_TopControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PART_LeftControl" Grid.Row="1" />

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" x:Name="PART_RightControl" Grid.Row="1" />

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="PART_BottomControl" Grid.Row="2">
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Label Foreground="CornflowerBlue" FontSize="14"
                                   Content="{Binding ElementName=PART_ContentControlGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" />
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Как получить доступ к этим самым частичным элементам контролла и стиля, что бы можно было задать им **Handler** обработчики событий?

Знаю что есть виртуальный метод **GetTemplateChild**, но он же возвращает **DependencyObject**, а мне нужен сам объект для взаимодействия с ним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetTemplateChild` — это правильный метод. Фреймворк не знает, какого типа будет ваш элемент, и соответственно не может предоставить функцию с нужным возвращаемым типом. Используйте явное приведение типов:

```
const string PartTopControlName = "PART_TopControl";
ContentPresenter PartTopControl;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    if (PartTopControl != null) // отпишемся от старых событий
    {
        PartTopControl.Event -= Handler;
    }

    PartTopControl = GetTemplateChild(PartTopControlName) as ContentPresenter;

    if (PartTopControl != null) // темплейт имеет право не определять части по своему выбору
    {
        PartTopControl.Event += Handler;
    }

    // ну и так далее
}
```

Кстати, контролы WPF внутри себя [делают точно так же](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Slider.cs,1278).

Comment: Да, так работает, но событие приписывается только после появления контрола, и до того как он не начнет делать что либо, взаимодействие с ним невозможно, т.е. обработчик как-будто и не ставили.

Comment: @Birdy: До `OnApplyTemplate` у вас вовсе нету внутренних контролов. Так что это самый ранний момент.

Comment: Хм, понятно спасибо за ответ!