# Обращение к внутренним контролам, которые находятся в Template моего UserControl'а

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Доброго времени суток, Господа. Хотел бы узнать, как можно обратиться к внутренним контролам, которые находятся в Template моего UserControl'а? Если определить эти контролы прям внутри UserControl'а, без Template, то по `x:Name` я могу обратиться к ним в codebehind. А если в Template их объявляю, то никак не получается обратиться:(
У меня в голову пришли только две идеи:
1. У каждого, нужного мне, внутреннего контрола подписаться на событие `Loaded`, и собственно внутри обрабочика кешировать `sender`. Типо такого:

```
private TextBox textBox = null;
private void textbox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox = sender as TextBox;
}
```

Но это очень глупо, на мой взгляд.

2. Вроде у WPF есть визуальное/логическое дерево контролов, в котором можно искать то, что тебе нужно. В принципе, можно по этому пути пойти, но опять же, это долгий процесс, да и я что-то не понял, как это делается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать то, что мне нужно?

Comment: По-моему всё логично, если ваши контролы находятся в шаблоне, то имейте ввиду, что пользователи вашего UserControl могут переопределить шаблон и этих контролов там больше не будет. поэтому и доступа к ним из кода нет.

Comment: А зачем тогда вообще объявлять их в шаблоне?

Comment: Ну это уже вам виднее должно быть, зачем вы их определяете именно в шаблоне

Comment: Я вообще не могу понять зачем эти шаблоны нужны? Я кстати теперь убрал шаблон, написал все контролы прям в внутри UserControl'а. Работоспособность из-за этого не поменялась. В чем прикол этих шаблонов то тогда? Ну стили понятно зачем нужны, а шаблоны? Если их каждый, кто захочет может переопределить и нарушить мой функционал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Для этого вы должны сделать следующее.

1. Объявите в вашем классе (наследующем `UserControl`) нужные имена при помощи атрибута `TemplatePart`. Правила хорошего тона также рекомендуют, чтобы имена начинались с `PART_`. Пусть вам нужен `Grid`, который вы хотите назвать `PART_MainGrid`. Это не обязательно, но является своего рода документацией.
2. Объявите в code-behind вашего контрола переменную `Grid MainGrid;`. В template'е дайте вашему `Grid`'у имя `PART_MainGrid`.
3. Перекройте метод `OnApplyTemplate`. Он будет вызываться каждый раз, когда template поменяется. В нём вы можете получить нужный объект при помощи `MainGrid = (Grid)GetTemplateChild("PART_MainGrid");`. Возвращённое значение имеет право быть `null`, если в template'е не нашлось нужного элемента.
4. В остальной части `UserControl`'а можно пользоваться. Учтите, что `MainGrid` может оказаться `null`'ом, и всегда проверяйте.

Подробнее здесь:

- [Создание шаблона окна в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443931/10105)
- [Получить доступ к объекту PART_... CustomControl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685856/10105)

---

Если вы переопределяете template не у вашего класса, а у существующего, то можно пользоваться `GetTemplateChild` тоже, но вы должны вызывать его в момент, когда `OnApplyTemplate` гарантировано выполнилось.

Comment: А зачем вообще шаблоны нужны, если они могут нарушить функциональность моего UserControl'а? Или нужно, все что относится к функциональности внутри UserControl'а объявлять, а не его Template?

Comment: Цель шаблонов — изменить внешний вид контрола, не меняя его смысл. (Ну и вообще задать вид: без шаблона по умолчанию контрол не имеет вида и является чисто формальной конструкцией.) Вам обычно нужно не это, а наполнить контрол контентом. Для этого вы пишете внутри контрола контент, и как бы всё.

Comment: Я имею ввиду следующее, допустим у меня есть SearchBox - TextBox+Button. Пользователь захочет, и изменит шаблон этого контрола, и уберет кнопку. SearchBox теперь потеряет функциональность, он не будет нести никакой полезности. Понимаете о чем я?

Comment: @Bretbas: Понимаю. Его право, он что хочет, то и получает. Если он переопределил шаблон так, что функциональность контрола при этом ограничена, он сам себе злобный Буратино. Для того, чтобы подсказать пользователю, какие части необходимы, и существует декларация TemplatePart.

Comment: Короче, я так понял, что в моем случае, нет смысла делать весь функционал в шаблоне, при создании UserControl

Comment: @Bretbas: Ну да, обычно так не делают, переопределение шаблона — это всё же для особых случаев

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Bretbas: Пожалуйста, рад, если помогло.